# javac -cp doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, glassfish, classpath, javac

I'm trying to add a .jar file to my java classpath when compiling an application and it doesn't seem to be working when I specify the location like so:

`javac CreateAccount.java -cp .:~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar -d classes`

Output:

```
CreateAccount.java:3: error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; 
CreateAccount.java:5: error: package javax.servlet does not exist import javax.servlet.*;
CreateAccount.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

Also tried using /home in place of tidle (~) but doesn't work either. However when I copy the .jar file in question to the same folder where CreateAccount.java is located and have this instead:

`javac CreateAccount.java -cp .:javax.servlet-api.jar -d classes`

It seems to work fine. I've checked path is definitely correct and the jar files exists.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Windows or a Unix of some form (when compiling)? My guess is that you're using Unix given then `~`, but it's worth checking...

Comment: Define "it doesn't seem to be working" in a scientific way: what do you observe? What is the error message you get?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be recognising the classpath, the errors indicate the it can't find the classes that are part of the .jar file.

Comment: For Christ sake. Paste the exact and complete error message if you want help. Leaving us in the dark doesn't help. Isn't that obvious to a developer that reading an error message could help identifying what the error is?

Comment: javac CreateAccount.java -cp .:~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar -d classes
CreateAccount.java:3: error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
                               ^
CreateAccount.java:5: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
CreateAccount.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
                                   
As you can see, exactly what I said before.

Comment: What is the output of `jar tvf ~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar`. Edit your question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `CreateAccount` only depends on `javax.servlet-api.jar` and if your path to this JAR is correct, then drop the reference to the current working directory; to wit:

`javac -cp ~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar -d classes CreateAccount.java`

(Note: source files should be placed after `javac` options.)

To validate the path to `javax.servlet-api.jar`, try this:

```
jar tf ~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar
```

You should see a listing of all the classes in the `javax.servlet-api.jar`; if you don't the path is incorrect. (You can also use `ls` to test the path, of course.)

The tilde `~` is short for the current user's home directory, so assuming this is Linux and you are `user1915747`, the above is equivalent to:

`javac -cp /home/user1915747/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar -d classes CreateAccount.java`

By adding the `.:` term to the class-path, you are adding the current working directory (`.`) and a separator (`:`). If this causes your compilation to break, the compiler is finding a match in your current working directory instead of in `javax.servlet-api.jar`. As noted above, if your source file does not need anything from the current working directory, drop that term, or place the term at the end; to wit

`javac -cp /home/user1915747/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar:. -d classes CreateAccount.java`

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the jar file, If I specify:

javac CreateAccount.java -cp ~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar:. -d classes

It works fine, but if I put the .: in front it does not, Also If I put the above command line (working) into an options.txt file and run javac @options.txt it doesn't work either.

Comment: As you may know, the `.` means current location, so do you have another JAR in your current directory?

Comment: No, I removed the old .jar. I don't know what the difference is between the .: and :. It states in the documentation that this specifies multiple classpaths, don't know why specifying one before the other would be significant. I'm also baffled as to why the options work when I enter them into a command line prompt but why I save them out to an options file and use javac @options it doesn't work.

Comment: I've added a bit to the explanation of `class-path` terms. Basically, on UNIX and Linux, `:` is a class-path term separator, e.g., `path1:path2:path3:path4` (on Windows, the class-path term separator is `;`). HTH.

Comment: Is the expansion of ~ be done by the shell when it is recognized as a path, that is when is in the first position? (just thinking aloud)

Comment: As @John Skeet asked, what is your platform? UNIX, Linux, Mac, AS-400, PDP-11,...,DOS, or Windows?

Comment: The `~` is expanded by the shell, @robermann, as is `.` prior to the invocation of `javac`.

Comment: Ok, but why "javac CreateAccount.java -cp ~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar:. -d classes" works while "javac CreateAccount.java -cp .:~/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar -d classes" does not work?  @user1915747 can you confirm you are having this issue?

Comment: @JanNielsen: shell doesn't do expansion of `.`, and it only expands `~` at the beginning of the argument

Comment: @robermann yes that is the issue I am having. I've checked the working directory and it does not have a .jar file contained within in, plus I think that it would only include jar files if you had .*: as opposed to .: I don't know why this is happening tbh, the weird thing is that specifying -cp /home/usr/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet-api.jar does not work either

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @KarolS; the `.` is not expanded by the shell, as I incorrectly noted above; it is passed to the JVM and interpreted by the JVM as present-working-directory.

Comment: @JanNielsen AFAIK, not by JVM, but by the operating system.